# Convey value from dynamic <select> to list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

So on button click I add new select, on remove I delete last member of array. Now I want to move selected value to list below.

This is my code:

```
  $scope.langInput = {
    count: 3,
    values: [1, 2],
    add: function() {
        this.values.push(this.count);
        this.count += 1;
        console.log(this.values);
    },
    remove: function() {
        this.values.pop();
        this.count -= 1;
        console.log(this.values);
    }
};
```

[This](https://plnkr.co/edit/b3TWwyKHrnQnYAzn56vV?p=preview)is working demo of my code. I want to move selected option to `<ol>` list. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `onchange` event of the `list` and there add selected item into `ol`?

Comment: No I cant figure it out could you please edit my plunker and show example?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Angular but here example in plain JS (ES6). https://jsfiddle.net/rpneLdma/

Comment: Well I need this in angularJS and the buttons must be present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write `select` as:

```
<select ng-model="n.selected" ng-change="onChange(n.selected, $index)">
```

However it demands that `langInput.values` should be list of objects and not integers

```
$scope.langInput = {
        count: 3,
        values: [
          {
            id:1,
            selected: "eng"  
          },
          {
            id:2,
            selected: "eng"
          }
          ],
        add: function() {
            this.values.push({id:this.count,selected: "eng"});
            this.count += 1;
            console.log(this.values);
        },
        remove: function() {
            this.values.pop();
            this.count -= 1;
            console.log(this.values);
        }
    };

    $scope.onChange = function(value, index){
      $scope.langInput.values[index].selected = value;
    }
```

---

<kbd>[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sfAZQhatnC0pT9BP9pUU?p=preview)</kbd>